# SQL WITH CTE NESTED

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Now I have SQL code as:

```
WITH cte1 as(....),
     cte2 as(....),
     cte3 as (...)
select * 
from cte1 
left join cte2
on cte1.col1=cte2.col2
left join cte3
on cte1.col2=cte3.col3
```

Now I want to do further queries (e.g. filter) based on the results by using the SQL code above. I tried to used nested WITH statement, but it does not support.

```
WITH a as (
WITH cte1 as(....),
     cte2 as(....),
     cte3 as (...)
select * 
from cte1 
left join cte2
on cte1.col1=cte2.col2
left join cte3
on cte1.col2=cte3.col3
)
```

Is there any efficient way to do further query based on the results by SQL code above?

Comment: Actually, some databases *do* supported nested CTEs.

Comment: Add one more CTE term. `WITH cte1 as(....), cte2 as(....), cte3 as (...) , a AS (select * from cte1 left join cte2 on cte1.col1=cte2.col2 left join cte3 on cte1.col2=cte3.col3) SELECT ... FROM a;`

Answer (score 0):

Eric, you don't nest them, just sequence:

```
WITH cte1 as(....),
     cte2 as(....),
     cte3 as (...), 
another_cte as 
  (
  select * 
  from cte1 
  left join cte2
  on cte1.col1=cte2.col2
  left join cte3
  on cte1.col2=cte3.col3
  )

select <whatever> from another_cte
```

As for `efficient way to do further query`
you might be interested in something "not-so-SQL" and preserve the results from original query in a temporary table or a variable. Depending on the database you use the execution plan might be much faster / slower, so check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the information!!